# iOSDeviceManager cannot install DeviceAgent-Runner.app on iPhone 7

Tags: calabash-ios

I'm running calabash-ios.  My tests seem to run fine on an iPhone 6s running iOS 10 or 10.1 but when I try to plug in an iPhone 7, also runing the same iOS, Calabash installs my app fine, but when it comes to the point of installing the device agent app, it isn't installing and eventually I get a time error after 60.04 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a combination of several issues which I need to remember to check every time I run my tests now.

1.) I didn't have UI Automation turn on in the device after I reverted from 10.1 to 10.0.3

2.) I accidentally copy pasted an old UDID into my .bash_profile

3.) I had to delete one of my provisioning profiles in my keychain access which was causing an 'ambiguous code sign identity detected:'
   error

4.) I had to 'Trust' the developer in the "General" settings section of the device